# Transfer images on websocket by using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-beast

I want to transfer image data on websocket by using boost library.

How should I resolve below error?

At first, I confirmed to be able to transfer and receive text data by referring following URL.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start.html

And next, although I tried to transfer image, I got following error message.

```
 websocket_client.cpp:563:38: error: no matching function for call to 'buffer(cv::Mat&)'

 ws.write(boost::asio::buffer(img));
```

What I did are below.

1. read image file as 'img' by using opencv.
2. Change the code for transfer data

   ```
   // Send the message

   // ws.write(boost::asio::buffer(std::string(text)));

   ws.write(boost::asio::buffer(img));
   ```

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html
You need to cast it to an appropriate format which is supported by boost buffer.
There is no matching overload which takes 'Mat&'

Answer (score 0):

cv::Mat is not a buffer type or adaptable as such. If you have POD data, then you can "cast" it like the commenter says:

```
 // don't do this:
 buffer(&img, sizeof(img));
```

However, that's not safe:

```
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<cv::Mat>);
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<cv::Mat>);
```

The type is actually not bitwise copyable. But since there's a matrix, there is likely a contiguous region of data that **is**:

```
ws.write(net::buffer(img.data, img.total() * img.elemSize()));
```

This uses [`total()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa4d317d43fb0cba9c2503f3c61b866c8) and [`elemSize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aba7a5ef00b22b70668fba575005dfe55), links to the documentation.

Now, this will be enough if the receiving end already knows the dimensions. If not, send them first, e.g.:

```
uint32_t dimensions[] { htonl(image_witdh), htonl(image_height) };

std::vector<net::const_buffer> buffers {
    net::buffer(dimensions),
    net::buffer(img.data, img.total() * img.elemSize())
};
ws.write(buffers);
```

Comment: I succeed to transfer image to server as binary.

But I can't show image.

How could I do this?


Error message

    img = np.frombuffer(message, dtype=np.uint8) #NG

    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I'm afraid you're in [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,them%20to%20resolve%20issue%20X.). If you had asked "how do I display an image received over websockets" you will get entirely different answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292133/receiving-image-through-websocket